# PhoneGap (Android) Delete Directory

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to delete a directory and it's contents with `PhoneGap on Android` using:

```
deleteDirectory = function deleteDirectory(uri) {
    uri = uri.substring(0, uri.lastIndexOf('/'));
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(uri, {
            create: false
        }, function (directory) {
            directory.removeRecursively();
            def.resolve();
        }, function (error) {
            resolveError("Error deleting directory: ", error, def);
        });
    }).promise();
}
```

with the following error: `File No Modification Allowed Error`

I've confirmed this permission is set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Where else should I be looking?

Comment: What directory are you trying to delete? Is it on the sd card or internal storage?

Comment: A sub folder added in the Nexus 7's Download folder: `file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/somedir/dirtodelete` I guess this would be considered internal so the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` will not work... will add `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` to see if that's it.

Comment: WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE didn't seem to work either.

Comment: You are not the first person to complain about odd behaviour on the Nexus 7. I have to see if someone has one to run the test suite.

Answer (score 10):

I have done it with this approach:

```
    function ClearDirectory() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
        function fail(evt) {
            alert("FILE SYSTEM FAILURE" + evt.target.error.code);
        }
        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getDirectory(
                 "yours/dir/ect/ory",
                {create : true, exclusive : false},
                function(entry) {
                entry.removeRecursively(function() {
                    console.log("Remove Recursively Succeeded");
                }, fail);
            }, fail);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127292/window-resolvelocalfilesystemurl-vs-window-requestfilesystem):

> I'd suggest using **resolveLocalFileSystemURL** if you want to access
>   locations under cordova.file.* (eg cordova.file.dataDirectory), which
>   is most of the time (if not always), and use **requestFileSystem** if you
>   need to have access to the root of the filesystem.

This also saves some lines of code and is more readable:

```
deleteFolder(fileName: string) {
    const uri = `${cordova.file.dataDirectory}${fileName}`;
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(uri, (dirEntry: DirectoryEntry) => {
        dirEntry.removeRecursively(
            () => console.log('successfully deleted the folder and its content'),
            e => console.error('there was an error deleting the directory', e.toString())
        )
    });
}
```

And here an awaitable version:

```
deleteFolder(fileName: string): Promise<void> {
    const promise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const uri = `${cordova.file.dataDirectory}${fileName}`;
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(uri, (dirEntry: DirectoryEntry) => {
            dirEntry.removeRecursively(() => resolve(), e => reject(e));
        }, e => reject(e));
    });
    return promise;
}
```