# How to remove files downloaded on sdcard with phonegap application?

Tags: android, file, cordova, android-sdcard

I am developing phone-gap application and I download images from my server to SDCARD for the purpose of offline use.

But I want to delete directory that I was created to store all these images when user uninstall the app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355641/phonegap-android-delete-directory