# window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL vs window.requestFileSystem

Tags: cordova, fileapi

What is the difference in using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` vs `window.requestFileSystem` when downloading files with the cordova file plugin? I cant find any documentation on resolveLocalFileSystemURL but it works fine, and its easier to use?

Which one should I use for simple CRUD operations in a cordova app?

(I use cordova 3.4.0-0.1.3)

I use it like this:

```
function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {

            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
               var reader = new FileReader();

               reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                    var _machines = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);  
                    machinesCache.setMachines(_machines.AllMainCategories);
               };

               reader.readAsText(file);
            }, errorHandler);

        };

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("cdvfile://localhost/persistent/machinedata/machines.json", onResolveSuccess, errorHandler);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at `www/resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js` and `www/requestFileSystem.js` in [the file plugin repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/), I would say that they are practically the same.

I'd suggest using `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` if you want to access locations under `cordova.file.*` (eg `cordova.file.dataDirectory`), which is most of the time (if not always), and use `requestFileSystem` if you need to have access to the root of the filesystem.