# Delete Folder From File system in phonegap for IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Can Anyone help me out that how to delete Folder in Phonegap For IOS.
I am able to delete File from file system but not able to delete folder from file system.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355641/phonegap-android-delete-directory

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, I think you can probably write this as an answer.